# How to create an exception that doesn't accept certain amount of numbers entered in input dialog?

Tags: java, regex, swing, exception, joptionpane

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{0,3}$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
if (m.find()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " 4 integers please");
}
```

It is a button that adds numbers

Trying to create exception that limits amount of numbers in dialog , it detects if the number is within the limit but does not stop the program.

Comment: It is a button that adds a number to the text area so if 3 integers are entered it should give an error message that I created above

Comment: @Java1245 - Should it be up to 4 digits in an integer or you want 4 integers?

Comment: only 4 digits should be accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `in.matches("\\d{4}")` as the condition and add to the textarea only if this condition is `true`.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number: ");
        if (in.matches("\\d{4}")) {
            // ...Code to add the value to the textarea
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only 4 digits please.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense , but the it does not stop the numbers adding to the text area

Comment: the message dialog does pop up

Comment: It gives dispatch errors

Comment: @Java1245 - I've updated the answer to meet this requirement.

Comment: I see , but this allows the numbers to the text area and it now does not show the message

Comment: @Java1245 - If you attempt to enter an integer which is not of 4 digits, this code will show the error message and the code to add to the text area will not be executed. On the other hand, if you enter an integer which is of 4 digits, the code to add to the text area will not be executed and the error message will not be displayed. Do you have a different requirement?

Comment: Was an accident! , my bad

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the context of this code, but it does not call for a custom exception. Just use a loop to display the dialog if the user enters an invalid input:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{0,3}$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
while (!m.find()) {
    in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please only enter four integers:");
    m = p.matcher(in);
}
// ...
```

Also, you want to change `if(m.find())` to `if(!m.find())` otherwise the "Please only enter four integers:" dialog will only show when the user enters the correct number of integers.

---

If you must use exceptions, just create a class that extends the [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)
class:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

    public MyException(int amount) {
        super("Only " + amount + " integers are allowed");
    }

}
```

And implement it in your if statement:

```
if (!m.find()) {
    throw new MyException(4);
}
```

Comment: I see where you are coming from , I have a try and catch block that does not accept letters , the code you provided still accepts the numbers. I guess a loop is the best way . Any ideas

Comment: or I could try != 4

Answer (score 0):

You've really provided less than needed code..

But here is a way to fire an event when the characters input in your `TextArea` exceed 3.

Lets say your `TextArea` is named `txtArea`.

```
    txtArea.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(newValue.length()>3){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " 4 integers please");
            //Do whatever you need after the Alert is shown
            txtArea.setText(oldValue);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think it expects an argument after text property